# How to do partial selection during reverse-search

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Usually I use `Ctr+R` to enable reverse-search, and repeat `Ctr+R` to go through the command history, then tap `Tab` to select the command.

However, something time I may want to do paritial selection, for example

```
(reverse-i-search)`sh /p': sh /path/to/the/a_script.sh
```

I have entered `sh /p`, and my history is `sh /path/to/the/a_script.sh`, but I know that I have another file `b_script.sh` under the same path, and I want to run command with `b_script.sh` instead `a_script.sh`. In this case, I have to `Tap` first, then change `a_script.sh` to `b_script.sh` manually.

Is it possible to do parital selection? for example, only select `sh /path/to/the/` part somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> searches through your history, and allows you to retrieve a previous command as entered.

There are useful bash shortcuts that allow to speed up the editing: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F/B</kbd> (or, more intuitively, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>) jump one word forward or backward, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> deletes from the cursor to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the command that you want to repeat exactly begins (in your case `sh`) you could do something like:

```
!sh:s/a_/b_
```

or more generally if you only happen to remember some string contained in the command and not at the very beginning, using:   `!?string?:s/old/new`  so that you can refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list containing `string` and edit it replacing some portion.
So you could fix the command with something like:

```
!?script?:s/a_/b_
```

The limitation of this is that it works for repeating and editing recently typed commands (it triggers the last entry in history matching the pattern between `!` and `:`), but if you need to reverse search through the whole history way back in time, then reverse-i-search is the only way I know.